# Verify SMTP code without internet connection

Tags: smtp

I don't have internet connection.I am writing a code for SMTP using Java Mail API.How could I ensure myself that it will work fine?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a mail server on your local machine and access it at 127.0.0.1

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would use postfix if I were using Linux, but that's just me because I have some experience with it. Google is your friend. Use the simplest one you can find. Maybe your Java mail api lets you set up one quickly?